IPC stream failed to read
While developing my unity project i setup a virtual machine with a windows 10 image to test out a few multiclient features. Because of steam connection restrictions i needed to setup my whole project including the unity hub and unity editor on the virtual machine. After setting up the project on the VM i tried launching it, but i got an unexplained error. After checking the log files i found the cause:
[Physics::Module] Initialized MultithreadedJobDispatcher with 5 workers.
[Package Manager] UpmClient::Connect -- Connected to IPC stream "Upm-1704" after 1.4 seconds.
Rebuilding Library because the metadata folder could not be found!
Source asset database requested to be recreated
[Licensing::Client] Successfully resolved entitlements
IPCStream (Upm-1704): IPC stream failed to read (Not connected)
[Package Manager] Cancelled resolving packages after 126.49 seconds
[Package Manager] Failed to resolve packages: operation cancelled.
Exiting without the bug reporter. Application will terminate with return code 1

I’ve tried several solution approaches such as setting some environmental variables, disabling the firewall on the VM and the host system or deleting the package manager cache. None of those solution approaches changed the error.
I am using "Unity Hub 3.8.0", the "Unity Editor 2022.3.14f1" and numerous third party assets in my project. For my virtual machine i am using "Oracle VM VirtualBox 7.0.20".
